# How to unbox a JSON value of Int-length to Long using Jackson?

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I'm using **Jackson** for JSON deserialization to `Map[String,Any]`. Jackson tries to infer my numeric types based on what it sees in the JSON. The problem with this is that sometimes I'm getting `Long` and sometimes I'm getting `Int` depending on the actual size of the value.

I'm having trouble trying to write a method that can just take the value and turn it into `Long` no matter if it's a `Long` or an `Int`. I keep getting errors in the unboxing because, without explicitly knowing whether it's a `Long` or an `Int` ahead of time, I can't seem to find a way to cast it to a `Long` anyways.

I'm trying this:

```
def getIntOrLongAsLong[T: Manifest](item: Option[T], default:Long): Long = {
    if(item == None) 
        default
    else {
        val result = item.get
        result.asInstanceOf[Long]
    }
}
```

I was hoping that by assigning the `item.get` to a `val` it would unbox right there, but it doesn't appear to be so. I've seen people using pattern matching for similar things but I still don't know where/how to do the cast.

Comment: doing a pattern match appears to work. If the pattern match shows an Int then I can do result.asInstanceOf[Int].toLong

Comment: If it matches `Int` in pattern matching, why do you need `asInstanceOf`? `result.toLong` should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try pattern matching, like this:

```
def getIntOrLongAsLong[T: Manifest](item: Option[T], default:Long): Long = item match{
    case None => default
    case Some(x:Int) => x.toLong
    case Some(x:Long) => x
    case _   => default
}

scala> getIntOrLongAsLong(Some('a'), 5L)
res0: Long = 5

scala> getIntOrLongAsLong(Some(1), 5L)
res2: Long = 1

scala> getIntOrLongAsLong(Some(1000000000L), 5L)
res3: Long = 1000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also make use of the `Integral` typeclass:

```
import scala.math.Numeric._
def getIntOrLongAsLong[T](item: Option[T], default: Long)
                         (implicit num: Integral[T]): Long = {
    item.map(n => num.toLong(n)).getOrElse(default)
}
```

This would also work for other integral types:

```
  getIntOrLongAsLong(Some(5L), 42L)          // == 5L
  getIntOrLongAsLong(Some(3), 42L)           // == 3L
  getIntOrLongAsLong(None: Option[Int], 42L) // == 42L
  getIntOrLongAsLong(Some(3:Short), 42L)     // == 3L
```

Comment: This is a neat solution. My Option[T] is actually an Option[Any] most of the time. Is it possible to make the implicit work this way?

Comment: I'm afraid in that case Pattern matching on `item` is the most convenient solution.